# Retrieving data from a different class on Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am using Parse framework for this and this is the code that was provided on the documentation on how to retrieve data from the database from parse.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Games"];                
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"JkaOj5lZ7w" block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"%@", gameScore); 
}
```

It works by calling the table name `Games` and on the second line it specifies which class it will retrieve the data from, and in this case its `JkaOj5lZ7w` and this is a default ID used in the parse database.

I don't want to search the scores by the default parse ID but instead I want to retrieve data by searching through a different class.

I tried doing this

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Games"];
[query whereKey:@"ID" equalTo:@"53056183"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        }];
```

I'm not sure if I asked that question correctly, but thats the best I could explain it.

I've been scratching my head on this thing for a long time and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a little bit about Parse terminology:

A `Class` in Parse is the same as a Table and and a column in a Table (Class) is simply a `Field`. Rows in a Table are called `Objects` where each one of these objects has a unique `objectId` associated with it. This is created automatically by Parse for each row when you save it for the first time. You can see this is stored in `objectId` field. I think in your question, you are using the term `Class` instead of `Field`.

If you want to search a class based on any other field which you defined, what you have tried should work as long as your `Games` class has a field called `ID` of a type String.